# How to re-use session.dat at TLSharp?

Tags: c#, .net-core, telegram

I connected to Telegram via TLSharp and successfully authorized, but I don't know how to re-use the session which I started.

session.dat I have in project path.

```
var client = new TelegramClient(, "");
await client.ConnectAsync();

var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("");
var code = Console.ReadLine(); // you can change code in debugger

var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("", hash, code);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hello! There are a "sessionUserId" parameter in the constructor of the
>   client object. You can give a unique value for each of your accounts.
>   In my case i use a phone number to identificate sessions.
>
> ```
> public TelegramClient (int apiId, string apiHash,
>              ISessionStore store = null, string sessionUserId = "session", TcpClientConnectionHandler handler = null)
> ```
>
> For example
>
> ```
> int apiId = 123456;
> string apiHash = "123456";
> string phone_number = "1234567890";
> var client = new TelegrowTelegramClient (apiId, apiHash, null, phone_number);
> ```
>
> It's create a 1234567890.dat file in app folder. Ofcourse you can
>   write your own ISessionHandler implementation and store sessions
>   anywhere you want.

https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/641